# Drupal and flex slider with images and videos

Tags: drupal, flexslider

Is it possible to get Drupal + Flex slider to work with both images and videos?

Using Drupal 7 and latest Flex slider.

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying to work this out myself at the moment.

My current solution is to use a view block with 'Views Slideshow' and 'Flex Slider Views Slideshow'. I'm also using 'Client-Side Adaptive Images' and the 'Omega' theme (plus 'FitVid' for responsive video... not sure if that's necessary, though).

I've got one image per (unpublished) node from my 'Slider' content-type for the image portion of the slideshow, and I'm using the body field for captions. To include video, I made a new node without an image and pasted a YouTube iFrame into the body. I've got a few issues that I need to work out, but I think this might be a viable option, at least for videos hosted off-site with a video-sharing service.